# HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp Message = "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: c#, html, pdf, file-conversion

I try convert HTML to PDF with `HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp`. My code for converting:

```
byte[] bytes;
var html = File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A3);
    pdf.Save(ms);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

File.WriteAllBytes(outputFilePath, bytes);
```

When I trying to generate PDF from `GeneratePdf` method I get an exception:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Stack trace:

> at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.Parse.RegexParserUtils.GetCssAtRules(String
>   stylesheet, Int32& startIdx)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.Parse.CssParser.ParseMediaStyleBlocks(CssData
>   cssData, String stylesheet)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.Parse.DomParser.CascadeParseStyles(CssBox
>   box, HtmlContainerInt htmlContainer, CssData& cssData, Boolean&
>   cssDataChanged)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.Parse.DomParser.CascadeParseStyles(CssBox
>   box, HtmlContainerInt htmlContainer, CssData& cssData, Boolean&
>   cssDataChanged)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.Parse.DomParser.CascadeParseStyles(CssBox
>   box, HtmlContainerInt htmlContainer, CssData& cssData, Boolean&
>   cssDataChanged)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.Parse.DomParser.CascadeParseStyles(CssBox
>   box, HtmlContainerInt htmlContainer, CssData& cssData, Boolean&
>   cssDataChanged)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.Parse.DomParser.GenerateCssTree(String
>   html, HtmlContainerInt htmlContainer, CssData& cssData)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core.HtmlContainerInt.SetHtml(String
>   htmlSource, CssData baseCssData)    at
>   TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(String
>   html, PdfGenerateConfig config, CssData cssData, EventHandler`1
>   stylesheetLoad, EventHandler`1 imageLoad) in
>   d:\source\github\HTML-Renderer\Source\HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp\PdfGenerator.cs:line
>   122    at
>   Plutora.Common.PhantomJS.PhantomRunner.ConvertHTMLtoPDF(String
>   pdfOutputLocation, String outputFilenamePrefix, String[] urls)    at
>   Plutora.Common.PhantomJS.PhantomRunner.HtmlToPdf(String
>   pdfHtmlToPdfExePath, String pdfOutputLocation, String
>   outputFilenamePrefix, String[] urls, String runOptionsFormat, String
>   runOptionsOrientation)

I have local HTML file with  inline CSS and absolutely linked CSS.

Why I get that exception? How to solve it?

Comment: Always you get exception? Try simple, little html.

Comment: @BWA, No, when I convert simple HTML it works fine.

Comment: So this looks like bug in library or in your HTML.

Comment: @BWA HTML is good, but it contains CSS links to the files. May be it is problem? How to work with CSS in PdfSharp?

Comment: It works without CSS links? Looks like problem with read CSS. Maybe bug maybe bad CSS. I have no idea. If CSS isnt big you can delete line by line in CSS and find problematic line ;-)

Comment: @BWA I have a lot of CSS. When HTML without CSS then PdfSharp works fine. But result is not very good. Do you have example generate PDF from HTML with linked CSS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155096/discussion-between-bwa-and-denis-bubnov).